# Why can unrelated c# interface references be compared without compiler error?

Tags: c#, interface

I was surprised recently to discover that the compiler is apparently not strict about comparing interface references and am wondering why it works this way.

Consider this code:

```
class Program
{
    interface I1 {}
    interface I2 {}
    class C1 : I1 {}
    class C2 : I2 {}

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        C1 c1 = new C1();
        C2 c2 = new C2();

        I1 i1 = c1;
        I2 i2 = c2;

        bool x = c1 == c2;
        bool y = i1 == i2;
    }
}
```

The compiler says that I can't compare `c1 == c2`, which follows. The types are totally unrelated. Yet, it does permit me to compare `i1 == i2`. I would expect it to error here with a compile-time failure but I was surprised to find out that you can compare any interface to any other and the compiler will never complain. I could compare, for example `(I1)null == (IDisposable)null` and no problem.

Are interfaces not objects? Are they a special type of reference? My expectation would be that a `==` would result in either a straight reference compare or a call into the concrete class's virtual Equals.

What am I missing?

Comment: For info, `==` is typically associated with the op_Equality operator, not the virtual Equals (plus reference compare, but you already covered that)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First off, note that Hans is quoting the correct section of the specification, but that the edition of the specification he is quoting has a typo which is relevant to your question.  The corrected C# 4 specification says:

> The predefined reference type equality
>   operators require one of the
>   following:
>
> (1) Both operands are a value
>   of a type known to be a reference-type
>   or the literal null. Furthermore, an
>   **explicit** reference conversion 
>   exists from the type of either operand
>   to the type of the other operand.
>
> (2) One operand is a value of type T
>   where T is a type-parameter and the
>   other operand is the literal null.
>   Furthermore T does not have the value
>   type constraint.
>
> Unless one of these
>   conditions are true, a binding-time
>   error occurs.

This explains your observation. There is an explicit reference conversion between any two interfaces because any two instances of two different interfaces *could* be referencing the same object. There could be a class C3 which implements both I1 and I2, and you could be doing a reference comparison of the same instance of C3, one converted to I1 and the other converted to I2.

Comment: Lots of good answers here, but yours most completely answers my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

I suppose this was done in a such way because you can have a type inheriting both interfaces and for this case such comparison could be useful:

```
interface I1 {}
interface I2 {}
class C1 : I1, I2 {}
```

So in the first case compiler definitely knows that objects are different but in second case they might be not.

Answer (score 4):

It is described very well in the C# Language Specification, chapter 7.9.6 "Reference type equality operators":

> The predefined reference type equality
> operators are:
>
> bool operator ==(object x, object y);
>
>  bool operator !=(object x,
> object y);
>
> The operators return the
> result of comparing the two references
> for equality or non-equality.
>
> Since
> the predefined reference type equality
> operators accept operands of type
> object, they apply to all types that
> do not declare applicable operator ==
> and operator != members. Conversely,
> any applicable user-defined equality
> operators effectively hide the
> predefined reference type equality
> operators.
>
> The predefined reference
> type equality operators require one of
> the following: 
> • Both operands are
> reference-type values or the literal
> null. Furthermore, a standard implicit
> conversion (§6.3.1) exists from the
> type of either operand to the type of
> the other operand.
> •    One operand is a
> value of type T where T is a
> type-parameter and the other operand
> is the literal null. Furthermore T
> does not have the value type
> constraint.
>
> Unless one of these
> conditions are true, a compile-time
> error occurs. Notable implications of
> these rules are:
> • It is a
> compile-time error to use the
> predefined reference type equality
> operators to compare two references
> that are known to be different at
> compile-time. For example, if the
> compile-time types of the operands are
> two class types A and B, and if
> neither A nor B derives from the
> other, then it would be impossible for
> the two operands to reference the same
> object. Thus, the operation is
> considered a compile-time error.

The last paragraph is why you get the error.

Comment: Note that you are quoting from the C# 3.0 specification, which contains a typo which is relevant to this question. "implicit" above should read "explicit".

Answer (score 0):

> My expectation would be that a == would result in either a straight reference compare or a call into the concrete class's virtual Equals.

This is true, but the compiler doesn't know this. This would be determined at run-time.